# Continuous functions as regulated functions: a property.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

In **Differential and Integral** by Paul Lorenzen (1971) pag. 148, I read *... every continuous function is trivially approximable by step functions that **have no jump** at a given arbitrary point ...*.
All this to say that an antiderivative of a continuous function is **everywhere** differentiable.
(It is a fact that an antiderivative of a regulated function is not, in general, differentiable everywhere).
Here I adopt the definition: if $f$ is a function defined on a compact interval $I$, one says that a function $g$ continuous on $I$ is an 
*antiderivative* of $f$ on $I$ if there exists a countable set $D \subset I$ such that $g$ is differentiable at any $\;x \in I-D$ and $\;g'(x)=f(x)$.

Please could someone explain why the italics are true?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a continuous function, then you can approximate it by step functions, this should be clear. but if you fix a point, then you can just let this point be in the interior of a step and you can fix it all time to be the value of the function.

be careful: here I'm changing the length of the steps.

Comment: I don't understand why I cannot do what you say with a regulated not continuous function.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo because your arbitrary point could be a point of discontinuity of the regulated function.